# Sampling in multivariate distribution with constraints on the sum of the result

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, sampling

I am trying to use a multidimensional Gaussian to sample material compositions in their probability distributions.

Let's assume I have a material composed of aluminum, carbon and hydrogen.
The average composition with associated std deviation is:

- Alu: average 44 %, std dev 19.6 %
- Carb: average 4.5 %, std dev 13 %
- Hydr: average 51.5 %, std dev 24.8 %

I construct a vector `mu =[44, 4.5, 51.5]` and a covariance matrix (I have some measurement to reconstruct the covariances)

```
sigma = [ 384.2 -199.2    -216]
        [-199.2    169     -68]
        [ -216     -68  615.04]
```

I am performing a sampling with n=2000 with computer script.
When I compute the mean and std dev of the 2000 samples, I found back again the correct mean and std dev. However, one constraint is that the sum of alu, carbon and hydrogen is 100 %. So, I renormalize for the sum to be 100 % but this has the effect to change my std deviation.

I illustrate my pb with an example, but my question is more the following:

**How can I sample in a multidimensional gaussian, knowing mu and sigma, but adding a constraint on the sum of my output vector?**

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Why is your mean not $(44,4.5,51.5)$? Why do you think this could possibly be Gaussian? ("Carb" is presumably positive and so right-skewed)

Comment: Sorry you are right, my mean is what you said, just a typo error and I changed it :). I just assumed it is Gaussian. It s an assumption that is approximatively ok. However, the correlations should be enough to constraint the problem to get 100% when I sum the output of the sampling, no ?

Comment: Shouldn't your distribution lives on the standard simplex: $S =\{ x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x \ge 0, x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1 \}$?

Comment: beta distribution would be appropriate here ... has support (0,1)

Comment: Or just check the multidimensional beta distribution or dirichlet distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution?wprov=sfti1

Comment: for example $x_{Al}=\mathrm{Beta}(2,2)$ followed by $x_{C}=\mathrm{Beta}(2,2)*(1-x_{Al})$ followed by $x_{H}=\mathrm{Beta}(2,2)*(1-x_{Al}-x_{C})$ but with the $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=2$ shape factors replaced by those that reproduce observed means and covariances

Comment: Thank you a lot. This idea of the dirichlet/multivariate beta is very interesting. I will try this and let you know if it works

Comment: How do you find the alpha parameters of the dirichlet distribution knowing the mean and the variance ?